# Getting error while trying to access a property in aspx page from a user control ascx

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am trying to access a variable from a aspx in user control as below

```
MyTestPage testPage = (MyTestPage)this.Parent;
testPage.ID // i am trying to accessing id which exists in the aspx page.
```

I am getting the following error while try to execute the above code

```
**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder' to type 'mynamespace.MyTestPage '.**
```

I am using master pages in my project.

May i know where am i making the mistake. I am open to learn if you know any better technique to access a variable fro aspx page to ascx control

Comment: I believe you should expose it as a public property on the page

Comment: I have like 10 controls and all of them need a property from aspx page , i don't want to do a setter on all the user controls

Comment: Do you want a variable or a control on the aspx page ? which you can get by **this.Parent.FindControl()** or the least **this.Parent.Page**

Comment: @i want to access a variable in the parent page which is aspx file

Comment: check this http://odetocode.com/code/450.aspx in this check this Master Page To Content Page Interaction you will get idea in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look this very good article, hope it will help you

[Mastering Page-UserControl Communication](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/Page_UserControl.aspx)

and

[Trigger Page Methods from a User Control](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131232/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031704-1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

do this  to access master page

```
    // Cast the loosely-typed Page.Master 
 MyTestPage  myMasterPage = Page.Master as MyTestPage;
```

also check this

[Master Page To Content Page Interaction](http://odetocode.com/code/450.aspx)

Comment: i am getting error as casting error to master page not possible

Comment: @kobe -- check this http://odetocode.com/code/450.aspx in this check this Master Page To Content Page Interaction you will get idea in detail